# Meaning of 'Shake oneself'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> He reached out and pressed an invitingly large red button on a nearby panel. The panel lit up with the words Please do not press this button again. He 'shook himself'.

What is the meaning of 'shake oneself' here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that he was shocked or surprised to see what just happened.

**Shake** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shake)

> *verb* 3.1 [with object and adverbial] Cause a change of mood or attitude by shocking or disturbing (someone)
>
> *"He looked genuinely confused for a moment, and then visibly shook himself"*
> *"Someone stepping on his foot shook him to reality again, Sally's big eyes willed him to stay in focus, but he just couldn't."*